# validate radio button not working jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, radio-button

How to perform validation radiobutton. failed to perform the radio button validation when use button type `button` instead input type `submit`.

`Demo :` http://jsfiddle.net/05qm3r4m/63/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myform').validate({
    rules:{
        foobar : 
      {
        required: true
      }
    }
  });
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/05qm3r4m/65/)

There are so many issue with your code.

- You have to give similar name for all the radio resides in one group, otherwise they work like checkbox.
- Jquery validation works on name for the specific element. So name is mandatory.

[Updated Fiddle with custom message](http://jsfiddle.net/05qm3r4m/70/)

Comment: Noted. but how can i show the error message with my own message by using html dom innerHTML ? for example document.getElementById("errMsg").innerHTML = "Please check!";... by using the solution you provided

Comment: Thank alot @Mayank Pandeyz

Comment: Happy coding :)

Comment: Radio buttons won't validate if they have property display:none. Option "ignore" resolves this problem.
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form').validate({
ignore:''",
    rules:{
        foobar : "required"
    }
  });
});